# AChartEngine point size

Tags: android, achartengine

I m using AChartEngine for generating scatter chart. I m currently using XYMultipleSeriesRenderer for rendering two scatter charts in a single graph view. How can i set different point size for each of the scatter charts

```
final XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
.
.
renderer.setPointSize(5.5f);  // this changes point size for all scatter charts

// Scatter chart1
XYSeriesRenderer r1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
r1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
r1.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
r1.setFillPoints(true); 
renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r1);

// Scatter chart2
XYSeriesRenderer r2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
r2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
r2.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
r2.setFillPoints(true); 
renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r2);
```

I want both the scatter charts to have different radii for the points. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: why don't you create two different `renderer` instance ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
mRenderer.setPointSize(20);
```

where

```
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
```